# django-social-auth usage example

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

Someone who has an application using the social-auth with facebook, I want to see especially  the use after login, as you take data that the user is already logged (birthday, photo, profile).

This part is not clear to me, because I don't know where the django-social-auth store the extendend_permissions data, I would like to use something like {{ user.social_auth.extendend_permissions.user_birthday }} (but offcourse it's doens't work).

Thank you in advance,

Max

Comment: Have you looked in the `extra_data` json field that each association has (`user.social_auth.extra_data.extended_permissions.X`)? Also, fyi, `django-social-auth` has been superseeded by [`python-social-auth`](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/)

Comment: Now the better option is use python-social-auth instead of django-social-auth ? I just want to make my user connect with facebook, but it looks too hard using django-social-auth... thx

Comment: Now I'm trying to use python-social-auth, but still having problems, look: https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues/48  thx!

Comment: Same problem with python-social-auth. How can I get the user profile settings, like: {{ user.extra_data.gender }} or something like this, i'm not sure.

Comment: Like this `{{ social.extra_data.gender }}`, assuming that social is a `UserSocialAuth` instance that you can obtain doing ``social = user.social_auth.filter(provider='facebook')[0]``.